# Im making a discord bot but im having trouble with troubleshooting. its giving me a couple errors but i dont know what they mean

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am setting up a discord bot. its gonna be a communication bot with certain commands. my bot wont turn on now because it gives me the following error code

```
E:\FLRP Communication\package.js:20
bot.command.set(props.help.name, props);
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at jsfile.forEach (E:\FLRP Communication\package.js:20:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at fs.readdir (E:\FLRP Communication\package.js:17:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I am using a tutorial video but i did everything just as he did. i dont know what more to do

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Config = require("./config.json");
const Token = require("./token.json");
const fs = require("fs");

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) =>{
  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("could not find command.");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} loaded`);
    bot.command.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});

bot.on("ready", async () =>{
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online! Its running on
${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
  bot.user.setActivity("Work in progress", {type: "PLAYING"});
});

bot.on("message", async message =>{
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
  let prefix = Config.prefix;
  let msgArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = msgArray[0];
  let args = msgArray.slice(1);
  let cmdFile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
  if(cmdFile) cmdFile.run(bot, message, args);
});

bot.login(Token.token);
```

i expect the bot to turn on in the first place (wich it does not). more errors might come after this one but it only shows 1 at the time

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `bot.commands` above but then using:

```
bot.command.set(props.help.name, props);
```

Change it to:

```
bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
```